# How can I close a C# writer that is in an object that is used by multiple other objects?

Tags: c#, .net, logging

I want to add the time to each line in my log so instead of writing it separately each time. I wrote a little class that I am instantiating and calling it from multiple other objects.

```
internal class Logger
{
    private readonly string logFilePath;
    private readonly StreamWriter writer;

    public Logger(string name) {
        string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        logFilePath = string.Format(".\\logs\\{0}_log_{1}.log", name, date);

        if (File.Exists(logFilePath))
        {
            writer = new StreamWriter(logFilePath, true);
        }
        else
        {
            writer = File.CreateText(logFilePath);
        }
    }

    internal void Log(string message) 
    {
        string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        writer.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", time, message);
    }
}
```

My question is, usually after using a writer you have to close it. In my case I can't close it in my class because I don't know when the object that instantiated the Logger is done with it so how should I close it?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`?

Comment: Implement `IDispoable` and use the `using` statement

Comment: I guarantee you will not solve logging problems as well as other people have. Please just use a logging framework.

Comment: It's not a big application so I don't wanna have complex logging stuff. It's a little project and I just wanna make sure that I am properly disposing the objects.

Answer (score 1):

We usually never close Log files, precisely because it is very difficult to guarantee that there is not a single line of code in an entire application that will attempt to write something to the log file after the log file has been closed.

That is okay because when the process of your application terminates, the operating system will close all file handles that were opened by that process.

That having been said, writing your own logging facility is not an easy task, so if you choose to go this way you will have a lot of work ahead of you.  For example, I do not see you flushing your log file anywhere; you will have to flush it after writing each line, or else your log output will be buffered, so you will not always see the last few lines that were logged, and you may lose the part of the log that was buffered if your process crashes.

Furthermore, you are likely to run into other issues in the future; for example, you may discover that you need rolling log filenames, meaning that old log files should be deleted; you may discover that launching two instances of your application at the same moment causes them both to attempt to create the same log file, so one of them will fail; etc.  All these problems have already been solved by creators of existing logging facilities.

Comment: So there is no easy solution, I need to implement a framework etc.?

Comment: There is no easy solution.  The advised approach is to use a library. If you want to implement your own you will have a lot of work to do.  However, I am not saying that implementing your own is out of the question; doing so has certain merits because most libraries out there (all that I have seen) suffer from their own extremely infuriating issues, for example they embrace silent failure instead of hard error, so if something goes wrong you have no log and you have no idea why. If you roll your own you will at least in theory be able to get that part right.

Comment: But you really have a lot of work to do, and you really have to know what you are doing.